# How to overlay unprojected image in openLayers 3

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-2, image

I need to overlay an image that does not move with the map layers. I've considered using the [ol.control.Control](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.control.Control.html), as the doc specifically states they can be "informational only," as in my case. All the examples of the control are functional (rotate, etc.), but I need a simplified example that is just the image.

Update: here is what I'm playing with (only testing with DIV, will replace with image), but the DIV does not show as expected:

```
    var forecastLabel = function(opt_options) {
      var options = opt_options || {};

      var $button = $('<div>').css({
            'background': '#f00'
            ,'width': 100
            ,'height': 100
        })
        .text("BUTTON!");


      ol.control.Control.call(this, {
        element: $button[0],
        target: options.target
      });

    };
    ol.inherits(forecastLabel, ol.control.Control);

      var map = new ol.Map({
          controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
            new forecastLabel(),
          ]),
   ...
```

Comment: Are you trying to overlay this at a specific spot on the map, or just as part of the UI?

Comment: Trying to position it in the lower-right corner, but not picky at this point. :)

Comment: Uhhh surely you can do something different than this?:
 `var $button = $('<div>')  .....`

Comment: @ThomasHorner Yes, as noted, that was just testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

Just specify an attribution for any of your layers that you have added to the map, pointing the image file you want to overlay.

In your constructor for the layer:

```
'attribution': "<img src='myimage.jpg'/>"
```

You can then adjust where that is displayed by messing with the div.olControlAttribution CSS:

```
div.olControlAttribution 
{
    left:10em;
    top:10em;
}
```

**Option 2**

You can nest a div into your map div, if you give it a high enough z-index it will be visible above the map.

```
<div id="map" style="height:100%">
<div id="legend"></div>
</div>
```

and then the appropriate CSS.

```
#legend
{
    position:absolute; 
    right:10px; 
    bottom:10px; 
    z-index:10000; 
    width:100px; 
    height:100px; 
    background-image: url("YOUR_IMAGE.jpeg");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas--I'll play around with option 2, first, as to avoid conflicting with default attributions.

Comment: Yeah, FWIW I usually just go with some div overlays when I want to have images in my map UI.  If background-image does not have the desired effect, just put an image tag in the div itself.

Comment: It looks like OL replaces the contents of the map div. If I view-source, the div is there, but when I inspect the div, it's gone.

Comment: I've never had any issues with that?  See this JSFiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/k7yybgLm/17/

Try replacing "HELLLOOOOO" with an image.

Comment: Sorry, it was my code; I was emptying the element for nefarious reasons.